# An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ContactsController'

Tags: xconnect, migration

An error occurred during migration MongoDB data to XConnect. The same issue was registered but out of the Sitecore stack exchange.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302183/sitecore-xconnect-an-error-occurred-when-trying-to-create-a-controller-of-type

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ContactsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at Sitecore.XConnect.Web.DependencyInjection.WebApiServiceControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Type 'Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Controllers.ContactsController' does not have a default constructor","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"}}

Comment: Did you get the reason of above error? I am experiencing same issue.

Comment: nothing helped until I reinstalled xconnect

Comment: Ive got the same issue. How did you re-install just xconnect @VladShpak?

Comment: @SteveWard Do not remember exactly. I think, I did whole re-install.

Answer (score 0):

check the password in the connectionstring.configs for the messaginguser match

- xconnect\app_config\connectionstrings.config and
- \app_config\connectionstrings.config

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following services are running:

[image]